# Julia DataFrame - Preferred way to update values in one column based on the values in another column

Tags: dataframe, julia, idioms

I am trying to learn the best way in Julia to update a DataFrame in one column based on the value in another column. I primarily use R, in which I can write this:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(A = 1:5, B = 6:10)
# A  B
# ----
# 1  6
# 2  7
# 3  8
# 4  9
# 5  10

dt[A < 3, B := B * 2]
# A  B
# ----
# 1  12
# 2  14
# 3  8
# 4  9
# 5  10
```

...which updates `B` in place where `A < 3`, and very succinctly too. The only Julia equivalent I've found is:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10)

transform!(df, [:A, :B] => ByRow((a, b) -> a < 3 ? b * 2 : a))
```

Is this the only method? And is it preferred? Are there any packages that can make this more succinct?

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can do this:

```
@. df.B = ifelse(df.A < 3, 2*df.B, df.B)
```

or this

```
df.B = @. ifelse(df.A < 3, 2*df.B, df.B)
```

or this

```
dfv = view(df, df.A .< 3, :);
@. dfv.B = dfv.B * 2
```

The third approach is something similar to what data.table provides, but you have to create a view separately first (something that data.table does in one command).

The difference between the first and the second approach is whether `:B` column is updated in-place or replaced.

Comment: It may be worth noting that, while a function like `ifelse` is very useful here because it broadcasts, it does not achieve conditional evaluation of the expressions for the arguments like the `data.table` example does. This means that if the condition was used to check for something that would cause an error this solution would not be applicable. `dt[is.character(A), B := stop()]` causes no problems, `@. df.B = ifelse(df.A isa String, error(), df.B)` does.

Comment: Indeed this is correct. I was thinking of adding an example of `((x, y) -> x isa String ? error() : y).(df.A, df.B)` but thought that it is too verbose :).

Answer (score 1):

While Bogumił Kamiński is the authority here and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66587724/15281224) shows a very nice, short alternative solution I believe there is room for more discussion and examples.

Firstly, your original solution is certainly idiomatic and I personally would prefer it in many cases. Mutation is an important tool for high-performance languages but it is also a source of many problems. The Julia convention (common for certain other languages as well) of adding an exclamation point (or "bang!") to functions that mutate their argument help greatly in keeping track of the places where mutation happens.

In-place assignments (`.=`) is also commonplace in Julia code but in my own code and in the code of many library authors these would typically be found in functions named in accordance with the convention so that the intent is clear at the call site. If you find that you often needed the kind of operation you're describing you could write a function:

```
function filter_transform!(df, pred, args...)
    fdf = filter(pred, df; view=true)
    fdf .= transform(copy(fdf), (col => f => col for (col,f) in args)...)
end
```

and to use it:

```
filter_transform!(df, :A => <(3), :B => b -> b*2)
```

which I think reads nicely. The function works for your original example but does not allow for assignment to another column or using several columns in the calculation or adding columns (like `data.table` allows, with `NA` filling the skipped rows of new columns). This slightly more complicated function achieves that:

```
applyif(cond, f, x, default) = cond ? f(x) : default
function filter_transform!(df, filt_cols, args...)
    colset = Set(keys(eachcol(df)))
    fcols, pred = filt_cols
    for (cols, (f, assign)) in args
        df[!, assign] .= in(assign, colset) ? df[!, assign] : missing
        @. df[!, assign] = applyif(pred(df[!, fcols]), f, df[!,cols], df[!, assign])
    end
end
```

using it:

```
filter_transform!(df, :A => <(3), :B => (b -> b*2) => :B)
```

Finally, you asked about packages there are indeed packages that you could check out:

[Query.jl](https://www.queryverse.org/Query.jl/stable/) (this example reassigns instead of modifying in-place):

```
using Query
df = df |> @mutate(B = _.A < 3 ? _.B*2 : _.B)
```

[DataFramesMeta](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFramesMeta.jl/stable/) (also reassigning):

```
using DataFramesMeta
df = @eachrow df :B = :A < 3 ? :B*2 : :B
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. There were several discussions about adding an equivalent of `where` clause to `select` et al. but since we have not settled how it should be implemented (the design is hard here) I decided not to discuss them on SO. Here is one related issue https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/pull/2467 (and other issues linked there).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński yes, thank you for linking! I thought about writing a explanatory note about why my example functions are not suitable for a library but that felt like too big of a digression. The reason it is easy to write a fairly clean two line function that solves the problem for some specific case is because you guys have been careful when developing the API and are not rushing the design.